# Inline coupon validation

Tags: expresso-store

I was wondering if anyone had already setup some inline coupon validation script that I could use on my order pages - something I could hook up with AJAX upon the user filling out the coupon form where it then queries the database and tells me if this coupon is valid and not used. If this is already available, that would be great! If not, just let me know and I suppose I'll create one myself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Store handles validation of the coupon code with it's {promo_code} tag by default. If you wanted to throw in a little AJAX that should be fairly straight forward although not something that can come pre-made as such as each form will be different. If you're using jQuery then I'd recommend [this plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#getting-started) and then just bind it to your form and promo filed to capture the response provided by Store on coupon validation. Then output that to the page. The plugin comes with plenty of useful examples with AJAX calls included and it should as close to a drop-in as possible once you've changed your DOM selectors to match your form and field.

Comment: "Store handles validation of the coupon code with it's {promo_code} tag by default", i've found this to not be true, it returns the standard (and down right ugly and obtrusive) EE error page. Doesn't do the inline validation as most other STORE form fields do. Am i missing something, i've tried to get this to work on STORE 1.0+ and now STORE 2.0+.

Comment: Hi Ben. I can confirm that Store provides inline error handling on the `promo_code`. If you're experiencing problems with this then please ask a new question on this forum and I'll provide a full answer with examples to walk you though it.